# sort across multiple files in linux

Tags: linux, file, sorting

I have multiple (many) files; each very large:

```
file0.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

I do not want to join them into a single file because the resulting file would be 10+ Gigs.  Each line in each file contains a 40-byte string.  The strings are fairly well ordered right now, (about 1:10 steps is a decrease in value instead of an increase).

I would like the lines ordered. (in-place if possible?)  This means some of the lines from the end of `file0.txt` will be moved to the beginning of `file1.txt` and vice versa.

I am working on Linux and fairly new to it.  I know about the `sort` command for a single file, but am wondering if there is a way to sort across multiple files.  Or maybe there is a way to make a pseudo-file made from smaller files that linux will treat as a single file.

What I know can do:
I can sort each file individually and read into `file1.txt` to find the value larger than the largest in `file0.txt` (and similarly grab the lines from the end of `file0.txt`), join and then sort..  but this is a pain and assumes no values from `file2.txt` belong in `file0.txt` (however highly unlikely in my case)

### Edit

To be clear, if the files look like this:

```
f0.txt
DDD
XXX
AAA

f1.txt
BBB
FFF
CCC

f2.txt
EEE
YYY
ZZZ
```

I want this:

```
f0.txt
AAA
BBB
CCC

f1.txt
DDD
EEE
FFF

f2.txt
XXX
YYY
ZZZ
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know about a command doing in-place sorting, but I think a faster "merge sort" is possible:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    sort -o $file $file
done
sort -m *.txt | split -d -l 1000000 - output
```

- The `sort` in the for loop makes sure the content of the input files is sorted. If you don't want to overwrite the original, simply change the value after the `-o` parameter. (If you expect the files to be sorted already, you could change the sort statement to "check-only": `sort -c $file || exit 1`)
- The second `sort` does efficient merging of the input files, all while keeping the output sorted.
- This is piped to the `split` command which will then write to suffixed output files. Notice the `-` character; this tells split to read from standard input (i.e. the pipe) instead of a file.

Also, here's a short summary of how the merge sort works:

1. `sort` reads a line from each file.
2. It orders these lines and selects the one which should come first. This line gets sent to the output, and a new line is read from the file which contained this line.
3. Repeat step 2 until there are no more lines in any file.
4. At this point, the output should be a perfectly sorted file.
5. Profit!

Comment: I never knew `sort(1)` was smart enough to open the input before opening the output. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it uses a temporary file.

Comment: That makes sense. Still, the end result is nice. :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you explain why the `-` before the `output` filename prefix is necessary (or what it is for)?  All other solutions but yours give me the error:  `cannot open 'output' for reading`  (searching "Linux command line horizontal pipe" returns nothing!) :D

Comment: Seems the others didn't read the [split man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/split/). I've edited my answer.

Comment: I _mis-read_ the manpage. It'd be a huge difference :) except I still got the answer incorrect.

Comment: Both should work. From the man page: `With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.` Since there is a file in my sample code, it won't read from stdin whereas in your example it will.

Answer (score 7):

It isn't exactly what you asked for, but the `sort(1)` utility can help, a little, using the `--merge` option. Sort each file individually, then sort the resulting pile of files:

```
for f in file*.txt ; do sort -o $f < $f ; done
sort --merge file*.txt | split -l 100000 - sorted_file
```

(That's 100,000 lines per output file. Perhaps that's still way too small.)

Comment: I am getting an error:  "cannot open `sorted_file' for reading".  I thought this command would create such a file(s)?   I was unclear on the -m arg.  Docs say: "do not sort".  Are you sure it will sort lines across file boundaries?

Comment: @Paul, sorry for that mistake! I forgot the `-` argument to `split(1)` to tell it to read input from `stdin`. I failed to notice that the `PREFIX` command line argument in the `split(1)` manpage is only a possibility if the input files are explicitly given. The `-m` option to `sort(1)` will select the correct line to output from the given _pre-sorted_ input files. It is the _final_ step in a [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) that correctly collates output from already sorted input files.

Comment: Ah! - It *collates* - That is exactly what is going on and is so  much more descriptive than "merge".  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that this is your best bet, using stock linux utilities:

- sort each file individually, e.g. `for f in file*.txt; do sort $f > sorted_$f.txt; done`
- sort everything using `sort -m sorted_file*.txt | split -d -l <lines> - <prefix>`, where `<lines>` is the number of lines per file, and `<prefix>` is the filename prefix. (The `-d` tells split to use numeric suffixes).

The `-m` option to sort lets it know the input files are already sorted, so it can be smart.

Comment: I am getting the error  "cannot open 'sorted_file' for reading" where `sorted_file` is supposed (I assume) my new files prefix.  Do these empty files need to exist ahead of time?  Also, the docs say the -m arg will not sort.  I assumed it only sorted the file names and merged them in filename-sorted order.

Comment: Er, like I said, you need to sort each file individually. I clarified the first step. And you're misreading the documentation: "merge already sorted files; do not sort" means that it doesn't sort the input files, not that it doesn't sort at all. Think of it as a single step of a merge sort. You can try it on a test case to prove it to yourself.

Comment: Er, I tried a test case.  Like i said, I get the error:  "cannot open 'output_file' for reading" where 'output_file' is your `<prefix>`.   (my apologies if i re-purposed your filenames confusingly.)  I think you have a typo.  Maybe you need a dash as in @JBert's solution?  I don't know.  Like i said in my Q, I'm a complete Linux "noob".  If merge sorts the final file, then why am I pre-sorting the inputs?  Maybe merge is doing something like interleaving the lines in an ordered way?

Comment: @Paul: Your last sentence is correct. The final output is sorted, assuming the inputs were individually sorted. When I said try a test case to verify that, I meant something like two files, one with lines 1, 3, 5, and the other with 2, 4, 6, just to see that it interleaves. And my solution is functionally the same as JBert's and sarnold's solutions; I posted slightly before them, and they made the first step explicit, used different filenames, etc. I'll edit in some more detail.

Comment: Thank you, however, your "sort everything" command should read: `sort -m sorted_file*.txt | split -d -l <lines> - <prefix>` to indicate reading from stdin.  http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm  (at least on my machine)

Comment: @Paul: Ah, right, you do have to do that if you're supplying a prefix. With no arguments it'll assume you mean stdin.

Answer (score 3):

mmap() the 3 files, as all lines are 40 bytes long, you can easily sort them in place (SIP :-). Don't forget the msync at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If the files are sorted individually, then you can use `sort -m file*.txt` to merge them together - read the first line of each file, output the smallest one, and repeat.

Comment: Although nearly all the solutions involve `sort -m`, I am still completely in the dark as to what a "merge" actually is.  The docs say only: "merge already sorted files; do not sort" which I interpret as "sort by filename, join files".  If they are merged as one file, why do you say: "..of each file"?  Your solution is the only that recommends I repeat the process.  Under what conditions should I repeat?

Comment: I was merely describing what the merge does.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm for a better description.