# Linux sort command efficiency/algorithm

Tags: linux, performance, sorting, command, mergesort

I was looking into the efficiently sorting values in a very large file. At first it seemed that splitting the file, sorting individually, and then running sort with merge against them all would be more efficient than running sort on one large file. 
[sort across multiple files in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693600/sort-across-multiple-files-in-linux)

Then reading this article:
http://vkundeti.blogspot.com/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html

It seems that sort command is already using a merge sort algorithm under the hood at a different abstracted level. Is it really more efficient to split then? Haven't ran any extensive tests yet, just wondering if someone knows off hand.

Is sort command multi-threaded? Are there memory bounds when running sort on single large file as opposed to sort on multiple file as separate processes? I know that sort uses memory for the sort in general, but temporary files on disk if the memory usage is above a certain threshold.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show sample inputs/outputs and your best attempt at code. Sorry, but requests for deep dives on code design, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: Is Linux sort the same as gnu sort? You can find source code for gnu sort [here](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/sort.c) . The initial pass does a multi-threaded bottom up merge sort in memory, writing a temp file for each chunk of the source file sorted in memory. Then it repeatedly does 16 way merges on the temp files until it reaches the final merge stage where it merges to the specified output file.